# Need Help on Looping Through Deserialized Custom Class

Tags: wcf, json, ienumerable, serialization

I am having a hard time figuring out how to expose (& loop through) the properties 
of my Categories class which was serialized (using JSON) in a WCF service and
deserialized on the server as illustrated below.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Category cat  = serializer.Deserialize<Category>(param1);

 // Missing a cast here?    

foreach (var c in cat)
{
    ele.InnerHtml += String.Format("<option value={0}>{1} &gt;</option>", 
        c.field.id, c.field.path);
}
```

Where (I gather) I am going wrong is that I have to cast my Category 
object as either ICollection or IEnumerable? I think this is the step
that I need advice on (if, indeed, I am barking up the right tree?).

Comment: Do you think that looping through the properties of a deserialized custom class is any different from looping through the properties of any other class?

Comment: Its not the looping that I am having problems with but the casting of the cat object so exposes GetEnumerator. If I am wrong here, would you mind providing the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to loop through Category which is a single item, not a list.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. Can you point out how to cast Category as a Collection or List or as IEnumerable?

Comment: What is your "param1" before you serialize it?

Comment: param1 is effectively dtSerialized which looks like this: 

dtSerialized = JSONHelper.Serialize<Category>(myCategory);

Comment: This is my Category Class:

public class Category
    {
        public Category() { }
        public Field field = new Field(); 
        public string model{get; set;}
        public int jsonkey { get; set; }
    }

    public class Field
    {
        public Field(){ }
        public int level { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parentid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Here is more on "dtSerialized" - 

Category myCategory = new Category();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  myCategory.field.id = (int)row["categoryid"]; 
  myCategory.field.path = (string)row["cat_path"];
}

dtSerialized = JSONHelper.Serialize<Category>(myCategory)

Comment: OK, I had the wrong type on the service end... sorted now. thanks for your help.